# Get data from each row of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` and it has an `EditText` in each row. The number of rows is between 50 and 60. I get the count of rows from the server. How can I get the text of each `EditText`? Can this action give me an exception error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this logic in your adapter and view holder:

```
class YourAdapter extend RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder> {
     List<String> yourEditTextContents = ...;

     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
          holder.yourEditText.setTag(position);
          holder.yourEditText.setText(yourEditTextContents.get(position));
     }

     class ViewHolder extend RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
          EditText yourEditText;
          public ViewHolder(View root){
               ...
               yourEditText = root.findViewById();
               yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        int position = (int)yourEditText.getTag();
                        yourEditTextContents.set(position, s.toString());
                    }
                });
          }
     }
}
```

After that, you can get text of edit text just use:

```
yourEditTextContents.get(position)
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can i get text of each edittext ?

You can't get text of all 50. You can only get values of those that are currently on a screen. When you use `RecyclerView`, you only have `EditText` objects that are visible on a screen. When you scroll the list, `EditText`s are reused, i.e. you never have 50 `EditText` objects even though you have 50 rows.

How do you load data into those `EditText`s? You already have all the data at the moment you load it into `EditText`s. If you want to get the data after user typed something then use `OnTextChangedListener` to get the changed text and update your model then.

> can this action give me exception error ?

Again, there are no 50 `EditText`s, so this is not possible. If you really need to get values from views, you can get it only from those that are visible. This will not give you any exception or error.